# horizontaly scrolling list of cards by dragging

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

i am making a website with bootstrap css html and js and i do not know how to make it so that the cards of products move sideways without having to use the scrollbar and just by clicking and dragging

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
        <h1 class="mt-5">Bootstrap 4 Horizontal Scrolling</h1>
        <p class="subtitle">Horizontal scrolling without CSS. Just copy scrolling wrapper classes</p>
        <div class="scrolling-wrapper row flex-row flex-nowrap mt-4 pb-4 pt-2">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-large-3">
                <div class="card card-block card-1">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" alt="Card image">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Some example text.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-large-3">
                <div class="card card-block card-1">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" alt="Card image">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Some example text.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-large-3">
                <div class="card card-block card-1">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" alt="Card image">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Some example text.</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-large-3">
                <div class="card card-block card-1">
                    <div class="card">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="https://picsum.photos/200/150" alt="Card image">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
                            <p class="card-text">Some example text.</p>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

i do not mind if it is js bootstrap or anything btw im new to coding

Comment: you are missing starting two `div` tags

Comment: @ShashankGb  yes you are right but i did not forget them , they did not get copy pasted so i just edited them in thank you

Comment: It's okay I figured out

Answer (score 1):

It is made of bootstrap 4 and some custom style to look more attractive and a JavaScript which contains a [mouse events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent)

**Click and Drag Carousel with cards**

```js
const slider = document.querySelector('.items');
  let isDown = false;
  let startX;
  let scrollLeft;

  slider.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isDown = true;
    slider.classList.add('active');
    startX = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = slider.scrollLeft;
  });

  slider.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    isDown = false;
    slider.classList.remove('active');
  });

  slider.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    isDown = false;
    slider.classList.remove('active');
  });

  slider.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    if (!isDown) return;  // stop the fn from running
    e.preventDefault();
    const x = e.pageX - slider.offsetLeft;
    const walk = (x - startX) * 3;
    slider.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
  });
```

```css
.items{
  overflow: hidden;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.2s;
  transform: scale(0.98);
  will-change: transform;
  position: relative;
}

.items.active {
  cursor: grabbing;
  cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
    <h1 class="mt-5">Bootstrap 4 Horizontal Scrolling</h1>
    <p class="subtitle">Horizontal scrolling without CSS. Just copy scrolling wrapper classes</p>
    <div class="items scrolling-wrapper row flex-row flex-nowrap mt-4 pb-4 pt-2">
        <div class="item col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-large-3">
            <div class="card card-block card-1">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" alt="Card image">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Some example text.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-large-3">
            <div class="card card-block card-1">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" alt="Card image">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Some example text.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-large-3">
            <div class="card card-block card-1">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" alt="Card image">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Some example text.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-large-3">
            <div class="card card-block card-1">
                <div class="card">
                    <img class="card-img-top" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f9/Phoenicopterus_ruber_in_S%C3%A3o_Paulo_Zoo.jpg" alt="Card image">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
                        <p class="card-text">Some example text.</p>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I hope I got your point and answered correctly. If not please mention in comment

Comment: so this worked only when im in phone style when in desktop it only worked on the page up aqnd down not on the div sideway

Comment: In desktop size, you want cards to be one below other?

Comment: when in desktop it does not work at all but when i go to inspect and change it to phone version it works on both the page and cards

Comment: I am not getting your point. This design is working for both desktop and mobile. You can check this code for any screen size [here](https://www.codeply.com/p/PbsXCgLhuJ)

Comment: i want it to go sideways without needing to use the slidebar so clicking and draging to move sideways like https://www.nike.com were in the 3rd row you will se what i want

Comment: yes like the one in nike that has multiple shoes in cards moving by draging

Comment: Did you run my code which is present above? It is same as present there. Click on card and drag mouse to left. It is working..

Comment: hold on let me double check it btw is there any way bootstrap is interfeering with this or another js link

Comment: yeh no it is defenetly the same

Comment: Check in stackoverflow's code snippet. Press run code snippet. If it works as your wish, copy all the links and scripts as it is to your local file

Comment: it works here maybe there is a compatibility error with my other links do you know how i can put the html of this one by itself

Comment: @MatheoGermanos  then working fine here right as your thoughts? Further I will help fixing this in your local file.

Comment: yes but i beleave the links on my page are fighting with it how do i make the links that are atached with it be only for your code and make other links not interfear

Comment: can you create a git or fiddle with complete code. It helps me to find where you are struggling.

Comment: i have to leave for 1h but when i return i dont mind zoom calling and share screening with you if you dont mind

Comment: Here it is midnight, I cant wait for 1 hr. You can post the entire html code using any online (there are many websites like [here](https://www.designbombs.com/code-sharing-websites/)). I will help when i get them

Comment: i will ad a post

Comment: If I given you a right answer. Just accept it. It will marked as solved Thx :)

Comment: i will get to you later its also midnight here so il show it to you later thx bye